# "compileOnSave" TypeScript source files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I tried to turn on "watch" switch but it doesn't seem to work. How should I achieve similar functionality using Visual Studio Code?

Comment: don't leave me < joking. I'm testing it out myself as well :)

Comment: @basarat Ahh, haha. I can't promise that, but thanks for your great work anyway! (And looking forward to your innovation later when the extension system is ready!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that something added a PATH with TypeScript 1.0 SDK, removing that PATH variable and add `"isShellCommand": true,` works fine for me.

Comment: I don't think this answers the need for compileOnSave. There is no such option in VSCode at the moment.

Comment: Think so. But it matches "similar functionality". Looking forward to that option. :)